# Show validity offirst order formula with semantics

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Given the two first order formulas:

$$
\vartheta = \exists y \forall x p(x,y) \\
\psi =  \forall x \exists yp(x,y)
$$

Show with FOL semantics that the following formula ia a valid first order formula.

$$
\vartheta \rightarrow  \psi 
$$

Any idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $M$ be an $L$-structure, where $L$ is our language. Argue that if $\vartheta$ is true in $M$, then $\varphi$ is true in $M$.

We start the process like this. Because $\vartheta$ is true in $M$, there is an $a$ in the underlying set of $M$ such that for any $b$ in the underlying set of $M$, if $p_M$ is the interpretation of $p$ in $M$, then $p_M(b,a)$ is true in $M$.

Comment: I thought I would just show that if $\vartheta$ is true then $\psi$ is also true (because if $\vartheta$ is false then the formula is true, so I dont have to look at this case). So when I take an arbitrary model of $\vartheta$ (model defined as a satisfying interpretation), I should show that the same interpretation holds for $\psi$. Is my reasoning correct? I don't see how I can show this. It is quite obvious that it holds though.

Comment: In the answer, I did not worry at all about when $\vartheta$ fails, for the reason you mention. Now there is basically nothing to prove, for $P(b,a)$ holds for any $b$, with the $a$ obtained from the first sentence. Note I had a typo before, now fixed.

Comment: Ok I see. I wonder though, why wouldn't the reverse implication not be correct? I mean I could find a counter example, but is there a point where such an argumentation like before wouldn't be correct anymore?

Comment: As you mention, you can find a counterexample, where there is no $a$ that "works" simultaneously for every $b$. To show semantically that a certain sentence, say the $\vartheta\to\varphi$ of our question, is valid, we have to show it holds in any $L$-structure $M$. To show it is not valid, it is enough to exhibit a single $L$-structure in which it fails.